# update joined tables using dataset wpf sqlite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml

I want to update my sqlite database from datagrid I have 2 tables marks and students
my xaml code is

```
               <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Name="dtGrid" BeginningEdit="dtGrid_BeginningEdit" RowEditEnding="dtGrid_RowEditEnding" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="dtGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

in stack panel
C# code is
initiaizes form

```
myConn.Open();
            myDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter
            {
                SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand()
                {
                    Connection = myConn,
                    CommandText = "SELECT students.name, marks.One, marks.Two FROM marks INNER JOIN students on students.id == marks.id where marks.classId = 1" }
            };
            myDataSet = new DataSet();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "marks");
            dtGrid.DataContext = myDataSet.Tables["marks"].DefaultView;
```

till this part

```
 private void dtGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
        {
            myBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
            DataRowView myDRV = (DataRowView)dtGrid.SelectedItem;
            myDRV.BeginEdit();
        }
        private void dtGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView myDRV = (DataRowView)dtGrid.SelectedItem;
            myDRV.EndEdit();
            myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = (Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteCommand)myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet, "marks");
        }
        private void dtGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            var tc = e.Column as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn;
            var b = tc.Binding as System.Windows.Data.Binding;

            b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            b.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
            b.NotifyOnValidationError = true;

        }
```

while updating from datagrid it retuning error "'SQLiteCommandBuilder cannot operate on queries with no unique or key columns " while I have primary key

Comment: Which line of code?  Also I see `myDataAdapter` being used multiple times, and left open looks like.  Is this a data adapter instance that you always keep open?  You should really avoid that.  Wrap each instancein a `using` block and create new ones as you need them.  That will help debugging as well as database use.

Comment: It's not the way it was intended to work; you don't load data into a datatable using a JOIN if you want to edit it and return it to the db. It can be made to work, of course (like everything), but you'll have to get a lot more involved in specifying the update query and configuring the adapter that will use it so it knows which source columns to pick out to send to the marks table while ignoring the student data. I would write a full answer that advises you to create a DataSet file and add tableadapters to it but I don't know for certain it's supported for SQLite ..